# Pairing Values from List in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list containing items such as the following:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I need to pair each item so i get something like this:

```
A, B
A, C
A, D
B, C
B, D
C, D
```

I am trying to get my list in this format: `List<string[]> itemSet;`

How would I create a function to loop through my items like so?
And by looping, i mean i could have 3 items instead of two like i showed in my exmaple.

**Update:** Another example:

```
AB
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

Goes to:

```
ABD, BCD
```

For instance, lets take the new values `AB` and `AD`.
`AB` + `AD` = `ABD`, because we already have an `A` in our first item.

Comment: pairing like u want key value pair?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Use `foreach` or `.Select()`

Comment: The order of the arrays doesnt matter right? so [A,B] == [B,A]

Comment: @Serv Correct, as long as i dont have any duplicated pairs, like: A,B and B,A as separate items.

Comment: Why do you want a `List<string[]>`? Why not a `Tuple<string, string>[]`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because i might have more than two items, Like ABC etc.

Comment: You need to specify that in the question then.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Looping refers to multiple iterations, not just two.

Comment: Your new examples make it even less clear what you want to produce. Can you precisely describe the transformation that you are trying to achieve (as well as provide examples)? Currently there is no discernible logic to it. Why does the second example do what it does?

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: @moreON Iv'e included something to make it more clear.

Comment: Why do you go from Strings that are two characters long to three characters long? Why is there only one element in the result list? This list of questions is not exhaustive. You need to clearly state the full rules for transformation from the input set to the output set, not just provide some examples and vague unhelpful clarifications. It just doesn't make sense at the moment. In the first example you take the input and generate the set of all subsets of the input which have exactly 2 elements. In the second example, no one has any idea what you are doing, but not what we see in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] array = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    var pairs = new List<string[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            pairs.Add(new []
            {
                array[i],
                new string(array[j].ToCharArray().Except(array[i].ToCharArray()).ToArray<char>())
            });
        }
    }

    /*output of pairs
    A, B
    A, C
    A, D
    B, C
    B, D
    C, D
    */
```

Comment: If i had something like ABC would this still work, or does this only work for two values?

Comment: @Sayse If you look at my updated question, this does not work? Did you try it?

Comment: @EliteGamer - Please read [ask], its not about whether I tried it or not, you don't seem to be showing any effort on your own part. And yes I just tried it - It shows the output exactly as shown in above

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] letters = { "d", "c", "a", "b" };  // Use LINQ query syntax to sort the array alphabetically.  var sorted = from letter in letters
             orderby letter
             select letter;     // Loop with the foreach keyword.   foreach (string value in sorted)    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);   }

---------------
Output
a
b
c
d
```

hope helps you

Comment: OP want to pair letters